# Zombie processes in VS 2013 console applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, zombie-process

I'm trying to create simple console apps in VS 2013, C#. Win 7. Running in debug, the window closes immediately (no "Press any key..."). Running without debug, the window simply appears and hangs.

The only way out is to close the window, but then I get zombie processes which can only be shut down by rebooting.

I know this was a problem under 2008, but I thought it had been fixed. Ideas?

Comment: Are you using Console.ReadKey() to wait for a user input to exit?

Answer (score 0):

Console applications won't automatically wait around after execution completes. You have to add in a call to ReadKey() for that to happen.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    /* all your code goes here */
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key ...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Could you please elaborate on what the zombie processes are (via Task Manager) and maybe we can help identify them?

Comment: 'm seeing the console processes just hanging around when I run without debugging.

I've added some ReadLines, and now I'm getting "Press any key..." at the end, and the processes have magically disappeared. This has got to be something painfully simple.